# How to remove the noise from wave file

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, fft, wav

I have a sound file, I apply a high frequency filter

```
   import wave 
   import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
   import numpy as np
   import scipy as sp
   origAudio = wave.open('3734.wav','r')
   frameRate = origAudio.getframerate()
   nChannels = origAudio.getnchannels()
   sampWidth = origAudio.getsampwidth()
   nbframe=origAudio.getnframes()
   da = np.fromstring(origAudio.readframes(frameRate), dtype=np.int16)
   left, right = da[0::2], da[1::2]
   b, a = signal.butter(2, 0.03,btype='highpass', analog=False)
   left = signal.filtfilt(b, a, left)
   hann = np.hanning(len(left))
   l,f=np.fft.rfft(left*hann), np.fft.rfft(right)
   plt.xscale('log')
   plt.xlabel('frequency [Hz]')
   plt.ylabel('|Magnitude|')
   plt.plot(np.abs(l))
```

I obtain

[image]

However I want to remove the noise from the signal , abtain only the peaks.Thanks

Comment: Please describe the noise that you’d like to remove? Also, why can you not read the peaks from the image you’ve shown?

Comment: @AhmedFasih Thanks, because I think if I take these pics, I can take the noise